# angular 2 windows azure github continuous integration typescript kutu

Tags: git, azure, angular, typescript

Please can someone help me with this issue!

I am using git hub to publish to azure and i was trying to set up an angular 2 app using typescript but i am getting this error in the azure web app logging

Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.

All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.

D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\angular\app\app.component.ts(1,1): error TS1148: Build: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided. [D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\TestProj.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\angular\app\app.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module '@angular/core'. [D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\TestProj.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\angular\app\app.component.ts(7,14): error TS1219: Build: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning. [D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\TestProj.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\angular\app\app.module.ts(1,31): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module '@angular/core'. [D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\TestProj.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\angular\app\app.module.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'. [D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\TestProj.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\angular\app\app.module.ts(11,14): error TS1219: Build: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning. [D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\TestProj.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\angular\app\main.ts(1,40): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'. [D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\TestProj.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\TestProj.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d3cc4c4d67c092";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository.\"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\57.50815.2378\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

Comment: Could you post the error as text instead of as an image?

Comment: @Vemonus this is the error: 

Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\angular\app\app.component.ts(1,1): error TS1148: Build: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided. [D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\TestProj.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\Zenklub\angular\app\app.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module '@angular/core'

Comment: I can build it locally but when deploying from github it doenst work

Comment: I meant in the question

Comment: @Vemonus i´ve posted the error in the question